# ACRA on Android fetch log before error message posted

Tags: android, logging, acra, bug-reporting

ACRA loging works fine on my Galaxy S2. I can see reports in GoogleDoc.

Problem is that a log ACRA sends doesn't really have error causing crash.
Example:
What I have in GoogleDoc:

> 12-06 17:59:03.605 D/CLIPBOARD(10745): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
>   12-06 17:59:05.380 D/AndroidRuntime(10745): Shutting down VM
>   12-06 17:59:05.380 W/dalvikvm(10745): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
>   12-06 17:59:05.380 E/ACRA    (10745): ACRA caught a NoSuchMethodError exception for ru.ptl.guidenavigator. Building report.
>   12-06 17:59:05.545 D/dalvikvm(10745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 278K, 52% free 2762K/5639K, external 123K/513K, paused 2ms+2ms
>   12-06 17:59:05.725 D/dalvikvm(10745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 399K, 52% free 2839K/5895K, external 123K/513K, paused 1ms+3ms
>   12-06 17:59:05.790 I/ACRA    (10745): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
>   12-06 17:59:05.800 D/ACRA    (10745): Retrieving logcat output...

and here is full report:

> 12-06 17:59:05.545: D/dalvikvm(10745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 278K, 52% free 2762K/5639K, external 123K/513K, paused 2ms+2ms
>   12-06 17:59:05.725: D/dalvikvm(10745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 399K, 52% free 2839K/5895K, external 123K/513K, paused 1ms+3ms
>   12-06 17:59:05.790: I/ACRA(10745): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
>   12-06 17:59:05.800: D/ACRA(10745): Retrieving logcat output...
>   12-06 17:59:06.185: D/ACRA(10745): Writing crash report file 1354816746000.stacktrace.
>   12-06 17:59:06.195: D/ACRA(10745): About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
>   12-06 17:59:06.195: D/ACRA(10745): Mark all pending reports as approved.
>   12-06 17:59:06.195: D/ACRA(10745): Looking for error files in /data/data/ru.ptl.guidenavigator/files
>   12-06 17:59:06.200: D/ACRA(10745): #checkAndSendReports - start
>   12-06 17:59:06.200: D/ACRA(10745): Looking for error files in /data/data/ru.ptl.guidenavigator/files
>   12-06 17:59:06.200: I/ACRA(10745): Sending file 1354816746000-approved.stacktrace
>   12-06 17:59:06.205: D/ACRA(10745): Waiting for Toast + worker...
>   12-06 17:59:06.240: D/ACRA(10745): Sending report 2847a23e-569b-400a-9808-2bb5fe08c657
>   12-06 17:59:06.255: D/dalvikvm(10745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 508K, 53% free 2832K/5959K, external 123K/513K, paused 1ms+3ms
>   12-06 17:59:06.300: D/dalvikvm(10745): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 230K, 54% free 2788K/5959K, external 123K/513K, paused 16ms
>   12-06 17:59:07.295: D/dalvikvm(10745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 430K, 53% free 2841K/5959K, external 123K/513K, paused 7ms+3ms
>   12-06 17:59:09.455: D/ACRA(10745): #checkAndSendReports - finish
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: D/ACRA(10745): Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745): ru.ptl.guidenavigator fatal error : android.widget.Button.addChildrenForAccessibility
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.Button.addChildrenForAccessibility
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at ru.ptl.guidenavigator.DownloadActivity.onClick(DownloadActivity.java:68)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
>   12-06 17:59:09.515: E/ACRA(10745):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-06 17:59:09.520: I/Process(10745): Sending signal. PID: 10745 SIG: 9

So the last message acra get is on 12-06 17:59:05.800

But error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError posted on 12-06 17:59:09.515

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's an implementation choice.

Check the STACK_TRACE field and you will get a readable stack trace (including the error you are looking for).

https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/67